# Failed lxd init

Tags: linux, lxc, lxd

It's failed after I run `lxd init --auto`:

```sh
$ lxd init --auto
Error: Failed to create network 'lxdbr0': Failed adding DHCP/DNS access rules for network "lxdbr0" (ip): Failed apply nftables config: Failed to run: nft 
table ip lxd {
chain in.lxdbr0 {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
        iifname "lxdbr0" tcp dport 53 accept
        iifname "lxdbr0" udp dport 53 accept
        iifname "lxdbr0" udp dport 67 accept

}

chain out.lxdbr0 {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        oifname "lxdbr0" tcp sport 53 accept
        oifname "lxdbr0" udp sport 53 accept
        oifname "lxdbr0" udp sport 67 accept

}
}
: Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory

      ^^^^^^^^^
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory

      ^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory

 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory

 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory

 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory

 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory

 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory

 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I've been trying reinstall a lxd but error appears again (lxd installed using snap).

Comment: I've been having the same problem for 2 days. It's not just the LXD init, but also the creation of any networks managed by LXD. 
I tried to create bridges manually with brctl and add them to the LXD default profile, but now I am stuck on how to configure the NAT and iptables. 

Did you get any luck on fixing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that this question is old, but I had same problem. After googling error message ended up here. Still there is no solution so this might help:
In my case lxc wrongly detects that I'm using nftables instead of iptables because iptables was empty.
I've added one iptable rule, restarted lxd and it's now working.
More information: https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/8724